# Передача значения из бд в функцию

Tags: python, django, база-данных

пожалуйста подскажите как передать значение из БД SQlite в функцию Python. Который день не могу найти информацию по этому поводу. Подскажите в какую сторону копать. Я хотел бы получать данные из БД, подставлять их в API запрос и размещать результат на странице. Теперь конкретнее. Есть БД, в ней есть поля серия и номер паспорта. Хотелось бы реализовать функционал подстановки серии и номера паспорта в функцию, которая производит API запрос к серверу.

Comment: Это называется "сделать sql запрос". Тут вот примеры использования API https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Тут все-таки еще `django` стоит, может быть человек хочет ORM использовать... Хотелось бы конкретных объяснений

Comment: Я хотел бы получать данные из БД, подставлять их в API запрос и размещать результат на странице. Теперь конкретнее. Есть БД, в ней есть поля серия и номер паспорта. Хотелось бы реализовать функционал подстановки серии и номера паспорта в функцию, которая производит API запрос к серверу.